# Does MLS update condition code flags?

Tags: arm

Does the “Multiply-Subtract” `MLS{cond} Rd, Rn, Rm, Ra` instruction modify the condition code flags in ARMv7? The [documentation for MUL, MLA, and MLS](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihihggj.html)  states that “S is an optional suffix. If S is specified, the condition code flags are updated on the result of the operation.” Is the S in MLS considered a suffix, or is it just part of the name?

For example, in the following code, will the final jump happen when lr != 0, or when (r0 = r0 - r2*r1) != 0?

```
cmp.w      lr, #0x0
...
mls        r0, r2, r1, r0
...
bne.w      0x1bc87e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that MLS does **not** update condition code flags, and there does not exist a version that does (MLSS is invalid).

Comment: This is correct. The linked doc seems to be a copy/paste error - the more complete ARM ARM shows that there is no space for the S bit in the opcode.

Comment: The linked document could be clearer, but it does not show the optional `{S}` for `MLS`